# Compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}[f(x)]$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to -1}[f(x)]$ for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1+x}$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Is it possible to rewrite expression $\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1+x}$ in order to be able to find its values near $x=1$ and $x=-1$ more precisely? This is a question in a numerical methods course. Is the problem ill posed from the start so you can't find a way to rewrite it?

Comment: $f$ is undefined at these points. Are you looking for a limit?

Comment: It is clear that it is undefined at these points, I think the problem is to evaluate near $1$ and $-1$, without getting the usual, the limit doesn't exist response.

Comment: Yeah the limits don't exist because on one side it's $\infty$ on the other it's $-\infty$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1+x}$$
has nonremovable singularities at $x = \pm 1$. As $x$ becomes closer and closer to these points, $|f(x)|$ grows without bound. This is true no matter how you rearrange the formula for $f$. However, for values of $x$ near $1$,
$\frac{1}{1+x}$
is very small in magnitude compared with 
$\frac{1}{1-x}$
so you could simply approximate
$$f(x) \approx \frac{1}{1-x}$$ 
for $x$ near $1$. Similarly, if $x$ is near $-1$, then
$$f(x) \approx \frac{1}{1+x}$$

Comment: It's even worse than that, I'm afraid. A term becomes unbounded in either case, but its sign depends on the direction of approach. The limit, therefore, doesn't exist in either case, even if you allow $\pm \infty$ as possible limits.

Comment: @MPW: Indeed, the limit doesn't exist. It's not clear exactly what Eesu is trying to achieve, but if the goal is to evaluate $f$ near (but not at) $x = \pm 1$ then the function is well defined. The simplifications above are probably about as much as can be hoped for (which admittedly isn't much).